# How to interpret data matrix in sensor_msgs/Image?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am subscribing to the topic `/camera/depth/image_rect_color` in the package [zed-ros-wrapper](http://wiki.ros.org/zed-ros-wrapper) to obtain depth information using a zed camera. Right now, my subscriber looks at a random pixel and reads the depth information. Is there any way to find out which pixel corresponds to what element(index) in the matrix?

Also if I run `rostopic echo /camera/depth/image_rect_color`, I find that the encoding is `32FC1`. But the data matrix is `int` (I believe `unit8` denotes `int`). Also, I haven't seen any value above 255. So, the matrix looks like `8UC1`. What am I missing here or how does a 32FC1 matrix looks like?

**Edit:** I meant `uint8`, not `unit8`. Sorry about that (Thanks to NEngelhard).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239939/how-to-interpret-data-matrix-in-sensor_msgs/image?/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"unit8 denotes int"
No uint8 is a Byte (8 Bits..). If you have a look a the image data type, you see that the data is always kept in a byte-array which is the most basic data type available. So the data-array is nothing else but just a pointer to the memory in which the image is stored. This data is then interpreted according to your image type. If you have a float, a block of four consecutive bytes in read as a single float value.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-21**:
But just like `float32` says that it is a 32 bit float type, doesn't `uint8` say that it is an 8 bit int type?
I think you may be right about saying that four consecutive bytes correspond to one value in the depth image. But are you saying that the array is made of pointers, not actual data?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-07-21**:
"say that it is an 8 bit int type" That's somehow correct. But there can be a difference in what you tell the compiler and how in fact the data is used.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-21**:
I have understood completely that the four bytes combine to form the 32 bit float information I am looking for. Thanks a lot for that. How can I know if this is a pointer or the actual depth information ? I am not able to understand why would you say it is an array of pointers? Sorry for being noob.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-07-22**:
"why would you say it is an array of pointers" I never said that. If you request an array in C++, you get a pointer (the ->data)  to the memory location where the first element of this array is stored.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-22**:
Okay I get it now. Thank you.